# How to access props from an externam js file - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, state

I need to access props in an external JavaScript file.

I have a JavaScript file which hold the static values. Like

```
export const SEARCH = {
  [Data.NAME]: 'search-default',
  [Data.LABEL]: 'Search',
  [Data.TYPE]: Types.INPUT_SEARCH,
  [InputData.PLACEHOLDER]: 'Search'
};

export const SEARCH_MAP = {
  [Data.NAME]: 'search-map',
  [Data.LABEL]: 'Search any address in the world',
  [Data.TYPE]: Types.INPUT_SEARCH,
  [InputData.PLACEHOLDER]: 'Search any address in the world'
};
```

I need to access the props at run time to set values dynamically. Basically I am trying to achieve multi-language implementation.

Is there any way to access the props here ?

Answer (score 0):

as u r exporting an object use . operator and access using that particular key
for example 
`const search = require(); //import file
name = search.[DATA.NAME]
like this u can access values in other js file`

Comment: Yes, I can import the file in a React Component class and access it. But I want to access props in this js itself so that the assigned value can be changed with respect to the language selected. I have my language strings set in props and it can help me if I can access  props in external js file.

Comment: if same file then y u need props!1!!

Comment: Looks like I miscommunicated. From a react Component class, I will be referring a constant( ex Types.INPUT_SEARCH), where Types.INPUT_SEARCH will be defined be defined in another file. I need to get the value mapped for the constant in the appropriate language set at that time. So when I retrieve the value, my external js will return the language specific value(Looking to get from props at run time).

Comment: Can you show the component class ? Or set up a code snippet to work on ? Or write pseudo code on what you are trying to achieve. It's very vague currently.